# Unable to loop through and delete child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following action method:-

```
try
{  
   repository.DeleteServer(id, ADusername);
   repository.Save();

   return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = id, description = tag }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

which will call the following repository method to delete an object:-

```
public void DeleteServer(int id,string username)
{
            var server = tms.TMSServers.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.TMSServerID == id);
            var auditinfo = IntiateTechnologyAudit(tms.AuditActions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == "DELETE").ID,
                    server.Technology.TechnologyType.AssetTypeID,
                 username, server.TMSServerID);
            var technology = tms.Technologies.Include(a=>a.TMSSwitchPorts).SingleOrDefault(a => a.TechnologyID == id);
            technology.IsDeleted = true;
            tms.Entry(technology).State = EntityState.Modified;
            tms.TMSServers.Remove(server);
            foreach (var switchport in technology.TMSSwitchPorts)
            {
                tms.TMSSwitchPorts.Remove(switchport);
            }
            InsertOrUpdateTechnologyAudit(auditinfo);
 }
```

the problem i am facing is insdie the `foreach` where the deletion will not be performed and no exception will be raised. when i debug my code the action method will call the deleteserver methods, then when the code reach the `foreach` it will not iterate over the technology.TMSSwtichPort instead the code will break without errors and the `.save` inside my action method will not be reached ?can any one advice what might be the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: `instead the code will break without errors ` - it might be a good idea to include said errors in your question

Comment: I might be wrong but it looks like you are iterating through a collection and removing items from that collection during the iteration... which breaks an enumerator (you can't modify a collection whilst enumerating it) - but then again I only glanced at the code :)

Comment: so what is the solution ?

Comment: @johnG Please post the stacktrace / error message.

Comment: @Charleh he iterates through `technology.TMSSwitchPorts` and deletes in `tms.TMSSwitchPorts`, there are two different collections, i think.

Comment: @MikhailTimofeev: `technology` is assigned from `tms.Technologies`; I think they're both the same collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine it's because you are using a `foreach` over a collection that you are indirectly modifying by deleting members.

Running your `foreach` over a separate collection might help, because then your enumeration isn't invalidated by the delete:

```
var toDelete = technology.TMSSwitchPorts.ToList();
foreach (var switchport in toDelete)
{
    tms.TMSSwitchPorts.Remove(switchport);
}
```